# Link para form de login joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla

estou criando uma página offline personalizada para joomla(Aquela de estamos em manutenção). Gostaria de colocar um link que direciona o usuário para a pagina de login de administração front-end, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

João é muito tranquilo de fazer isso.

Siga esses paços:

1 - Vá na pasta raiz onde o site está instalado. (é a primeira pasta onde estão todas as outras pastas do Joomla etc.)
2 - Pegue o arquivo `index.php` e o renomeie, tipo "no-index.php"
3 - Agora coloque na pasta o seu index novo, pode ser um `index.html` ou `.php` mesmo se for o caso...

Nesse seu novo index basta colocar um link para a página de login do Administrador. Tipo assim:

```
<a href="http://localhost/seusite/administrator">Login Painel Administrador</a>
```

**Aqui tem um index.html completo**. Basta vc pegar esse código salvar como um index.html, e colocar na raiz do seu site locahost para testar. ***Lembre-se de renomear o index.php que já está lá***, simples assim! Mas se tiver alguma dúvida é só comentar ok.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <a href="http://localhost/seusite/administrator">Login Painel Administrador</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @JoãoFerreira dmr jovem tmj!